# Print all chars in a String with delay in the same line

Tags: python

I'm trying to animate a little loading screen for a console application.
I want some lines of code to be printed, but every char should be printed delayed so i get some sort of a writing effect.

I have tried this:

```py
import time
text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.
"""
count = 0
while count < len(text):
    print(text[count], end="")
    count += 1
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

But when i run that code it just prints a whole line when its finished. So after "*number of chars in line* * *0.01sec*"the whole line gets printed at the same time.

```py
import time
import os
text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam."""
newText = ""
count = 0
while count < len(text):
    os.system('cls')
    newText = newText + text[count]
    print(newText)
    count += 1
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

I also tried this, but thats just a silly idea cause the screen is flickering because of the rapid updates.

Any idea how to improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `flush=True` to your print statement to continue printing on the same line:

```
import time
text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.
"""
count = 0
while count < len(text):
    print(text[count], end="", flush=True)
    count += 1
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell python to flush the output. normally file I/O is buffered for performance. (For terminals stdout it's buffered line wise)
flushing allows to see the result immediately even if no "\n" is reached

```
import time
import sys
text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.
"""
count = 0
while count < len(text):
    print(text[count], end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    count += 1
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

my answer would work for python2 and python3 As @ArnoMaeckelberghe pointed out:

With python3 you get the same thing with one line less by just adding `,flush=True` as parameter to the print function call

In fact @ArnoMaeckelberghe's solution can also work for python2 if one can add

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

At the beginning of the file.  If the file contains other print statements all of them had to be made python3 compatible

Comment: Good point that my solution indeed only works as from Python 3. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ArnoMaeckelberghe

Well one shouldn't code for python2 anymore or if really necessary only with future statements and compatibility librearies to allow easier switching to py3 ASAP

And i fact after thinking. There is a way to use the same code with python2 if enabling the print function. I adapted my answer.